# Paypal: Button code is passing all variables but paypal is rejecting them

Tags: php, html, paypal, e-commerce, payment

Paypal is NOT showing:

- TOTALamount
- itemNUMBER
- TAXamount
- INVOICEnumber

Paypal **IS** showing only the *itemNAME* variable in this code below:

```
<FORM action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="whatever@whatever.what">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXIDXXX">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo$itemNAME;?>"><!--127 chars-->
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo$itemNUMBER;?>"><!--127 chars-->
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="<?php echo$TAXamount;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="taxrate" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo$TOTALamount;?>"><!-- 127 chars-->
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo$INVOICEnumber;?>">

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.whatever.what/notify">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.whatever.what/return">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to the store.">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.whatever.what/cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://www.whatever.what/logo.png">
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_logo_image" value="http://www.whatever.what/logo150x50.png">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add instructions here:">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I have my own separate test file and all variables are visible after clicking *BUY NOW* button.
I've checked different values, but they are not visible on paypal (except the *itemNAME* variable).
What could be wrong there ([link to code](http://codepad.org/WuLakyvT))?

Comment: HAve you checked the generated HTML of your form? That's more important than the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an HTML or PHP issue but a Paypal issue.

Your form is using the input `hosted_button_id` with a specific Saved Button ID.

If you're using a Saved Button that you created in Paypal, you can't pass in most of these variables because Paypal sets those based on the Saved Button information. You can include variables that will pre-populate the purchaser's information, like their name and address. However, the item number, tax rate, etc, are all set inside that Saved Button's details through the Paypal site.

If you want to pass all those variables through the form instead, you have to ditch the `hosted_button_id` input.

Here's more on it:

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics#id08A6F0S0URO

Comment: DETAILS:
Each item has its own: EAN barcode, name, price, quantity, VAT amount (GBP).
According to above I need variables for all, or I can collect all details in one "INVOICE FEE" variable where I need variables like: Invoice ID, Invoice number, Date of order.
Customers have to leave: Their address (name+surname or just a business name instead), Shipping address (name+surname or business name), business VAT number.
Questions:
What kind of button should I use (or how to fix my code)?
Do I have to use SSL to send all required details (or just the button redirecting to paypal is enough)?

Comment: Try it as is, without the input for hosted_button_id

Comment: [SOLVED]
Thank you for your help. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to rate your answers, because my problem appeared completely somewhere else and I solved it just by myself :)

Comment: @dryhay Hurray! What was it?